# org-mode: Agenda View doesn't show any items

Tags: org-mode

when I press c-c a a agenda view doesnt list any items, but when i press c-c a n agenda view lists week and todo items.

I have already added the org files to front.

Am I using the agenda view wrong?

Comment: Lets start with the basics, does your `.org` file look like '* TODO Clean gutter *new line* SCHEDULED: <YYYY-MM-DD>"?

Comment: ah thank you. I had to add a schedule on the Todo bullets.

Comment: Yes. I assume your file looked like "* House project *new line* - clean gutters" and you wanted to see "clean gutter" in your agenda. I essentially had the same idea as you, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3tpd5z/a_different_way_to_use_org_xpost_rorgmode/